# Javascript, log what causes a boolean expression to fail

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection

I have a complex predicate in JavaScript that chains various tests against a value.

I'd love to log *where* in the expression it fails, if it fails. Sort of like testing libraries that log out where an exception fails.

Is there some sort of reflection I can do to extract some pretty description of what caused an expression to fail?

e.g.,

```
const predicate = a.foo == 1 && a.bar < 3 && someOtherPredicate(a.bar)

// if predicate == false, console.log ->
// "error: b.bar < 3 evaluated to false"

(I'm actually interested in doing this in Typescript, but want to see what features JavaScript has that could enable this)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t have anything like that. You’ll have to break it into separate expressions and variables

Comment: I was kind of expecting that to be the answer, that's a shame.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try debugging to check where this expression actually failing. put debugger; before your expression open up the console tab and keep observing your output w.r.t. your input

Comment: This is for declarative rules for database access, kind of like Firebase database rules if you're familiar with that. I want to understand why a predicate fails, so I can see in server logs what caused a particular request to get denied.

Right now the rules are plain javascript. I think that if I really want to do this, I need to create a DSL with an interpreter, and have the output I'm looking for be generated during evaluation.